# R: Reshape rows to columns and fill with NA

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe with **0-3** rows depending on the underlying data. Here is an example with 2 rows:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1), v = c(1, 2))
     ID     v
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
```

I now want to convert each row of v into a separate column. As I have 3 rows at maximum, the result should look like this:

```
     ID v1       v2    v3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 NA        1     2
```

Whats the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a condition that fix v = 1 to v2

Comment: Yes,  i mean missing rows  should be filled  with  NA, beginning  from v3 back to v1. That mans if there is only one row  than v1  and v2 should be NA

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(nm = str_c("v", 2:3)) %>% 
  complete(ID, nm = str_c("v", 1:3)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = nm, values_from = v)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**  Op request, see comments:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(cur_data()[seq(max_n),]) %>% 
  arrange(!is.na(v), v) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row,
              values_from = v,
              names_glue = "v_{.name}")
```

```
     ID   v_1   v_2   v_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA     1     2
```

**First answer:**
Maybe something like this:

What we are doing here is:

1. define the max of your group (in this case it is 3)
   then fill up each group to max of 3 with adding `NA`
2. For naming add a `row_number()` column and use `pivot_wider` with it'S arguments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

max_n <- 3

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(cur_data()[seq(max_n),]) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = row,
              values_from = v,
              names_glue = "v_{.name}")
```

```
     ID   v_1   v_2   v_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     2    NA
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to start the fills  with NA from v1 ? That is if there would be one  row  than v1 and v2 should be NA

Comment: This is possible. Just add this line `arrange(!is.na(v), v) %>%` before `row`. See my update!